# Creating a consumer of a Web Service WSDL/SOAP

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am attempting to write a Windows Desktop App (using WCF) that is a consumer of a web service.

**The application:**

- Sends a SOAP message to a British Government Server to get an authentication token based on the arugments passed
- Retrieves a response from that server in the form of a string which contains the authentication token.

I have a template of the SOAP message from the British Government, and a WSDL file for the service.

**What I have tried**

1. Add a service reference using the WSDL file.  I received the following error: URI formats are not supported.
2. Add a Web Reference using the URL of the service. I received the following error: The request failed with HTTP status 405: Method Not Allowed.
3. Send the SOAP request using a POST.  The Call to GetResponse() threw a 500 External Server Error.

NOTE: I am using VS 2005

WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:conv="http://www.openuri.org/2002/04/soap/conversation/" xmlns:cw="http://www.openuri.org/2002/04/wsdl/conversation/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:jms="http://www.openuri.org/2002/04/wsdl/jms/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:s1="https://tpvs.hmrc.gov.uk/dpsauthentication" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" targetNamespace="https://tpvs.hmrc.gov.uk/dpsauthentication">
    <types>
        <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="https://tpvs.hmrc.gov.uk/dpsauthentication" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="https://tpvs.hmrc.gov.uk/dpsauthentication">
            <s:element name="DPSrequestToken">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element name="version" type="s:int"/>
                        <s:element name="vendorID" type="s:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="DPSrequestTokenResponse">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element name="DPSrequestTokenResult" type="s:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
        </s:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="DPSrequestTokenSoapIn">
        <part name="parameters" element="s1:DPSrequestToken"/>
    </message>
    <message name="DPSrequestTokenSoapOut">
        <part name="parameters" element="s1:DPSrequestTokenResponse"/> 
    </message>
    <portType name="dpsauthenticationSoap">
        <operation name="DPSrequestToken">
            <input message="s1:DPSrequestTokenSoapIn"/>
            <output message="s1:DPSrequestTokenSoapOut"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="dpsauthenticationSoap" type="s1:dpsauthenticationSoap"> 
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="DPSrequestToken">
            <soap:operation soapAction="https://tpvs.hmrc.gov.uk/dpsauthentication/DPSrequestToken" style="document"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="dpsauthentication">
        <port name="dpsauthenticationSoap" binding="s1:dpsauthenticationSoap">
            <soap:address location="https://dps.ws.hmrc.gov.uk/dpsauthentication/service"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

SOAP:

```
<!-- v1.1 30/11/2007 -->
<!-- 24/10/2011 - minor change to remove duplicated text from <Envelope> element. No impact on validation, therefore not re-versioned. -->
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>as advised by SDS team</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>as advised by SDS team</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <m:DPSrequestToken xmlns:m="https://tpvs.hmrc.gov.uk/dpsauthentication">
            <m:version>1</m:version>
            <m:vendorID>your 4 digit vendorID</m:vendorID>
        </m:DPSrequestToken>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: "This is the first time I have written this type of application and I am stuck."  That fact that you have posted here notifies all of us that you are stuck.  But, in order to help you, we need to know _where/why_ you are stuck.  Please post your code and the stack trace(s) for any/all exceptions.

Comment: @Brian  You can see the code for attempt 3 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223771/call-to-getresponse-is-throwing-500-internal-server-error                                  Attempt 1 and 2 do not evolve code.  And stem from a lack of understanding of Web Services, SOAP, WSDL, VS2005 or the Documentation.  A Stack trace would only be relevant to the 3rd thing I have tried as the first two are VS tools and not part of code that is executing.

Comment: If you are using VS2005, then how are you using a service reference?

Comment: @JohnSaunders When I right click on the project it gives me 'Add Service Reference...' as an option.

Comment: please publish the wsdl and the sample soap

Comment: @JohnSaunders I have tried adding my WSDL as a service reference in VS2008 in an empty project and it works.  The problem is that the project I am workin on is in 2005.

Comment: Then you're probably not using VS2005. There was a hack that allowed you to use a few .NET 3.0 features with VS2005 (like service references), but I sure hope that's not what you're using.

Comment: @JohnSaunders How would I find out?

Comment: Use the "About" command in the "Help" menu.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Microsoft Visual Studio 2005
Version 8.0.50727.867  (vsvista.050727-8600)
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 2.0.50727 SP2

Comment: Ok, that's just plain not going to work. You need at least VS2008 to use WCF practically. The code that worked with VS2005 was a preview only, and it makes no sense to use it for new code.

Comment: However, this looks like a problem with the service, not with the code. It's based on SharePoint, and does not appear to be configured correctly. It returns the error "There was an error downloading 'https://dps.ws.hmrc.gov.uk/dpsauthentication/service/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 405: Method Not Allowed." It does not appear to be configured to return metadata.

Comment: seems like a simple wsdl, very depressing that VS does not support it ootb... for option #1 did you try the same wsdl url as with otehr options? any inenr exception or something that appears in the error pane afterwords? as for options #2, #3 this may be related to http headers, especially content-type. use fiddler to see what message body and http headers you send and compare them to the right ones from a successfull invocation. also see in case #2 if a response actually comes back with some content.

Comment: @JohnSaunders "The code that worked with VS2005" do you know were I could find documentation on that?

Comment: @YaronNaveh: I'm getting the 405 just with IE. It's not a Visual Studio issue.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - probably since IE uses GET and not POST. But I still recommend to see the expected content-type in a valid request.

Comment: @JohnSaunders  "Ok, that's just plain not going to work. You need at least VS2008 to use WCF practically. The code that worked with VS2005 was a preview only, and it makes no sense to use it for new code." do you know where I could find documentation for that?

Comment: Maybe in "common sense"? You must be using the ["Visual Studio Extensions for .NET 3.0"](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=31151) or whatever it's called. There's no sense in using code from 2006 which was clearly created as an interim release before Visual Studio 2008 and .NET 3.5 were released.

Comment: @JohnSaunders The reason I ask is that if what I am trying to do is not possible(with a reasonable amount of effort).  I need to document it for the project that I am working on, and put it in the 'We need to update to VS2010 and .NET 4.0' Bucket :)

Comment: I would say, "we're using an obsolete tool set. We should upgrade to VS2010 and either .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0". FYI, .NET 3.5 has the benefit (if your people are paranoid) that it is just .NET 2.0 SP1 and SP2 plus some extra assemblies. No change in the CLR. BTW, my main reason for pushing you to upgrade is that you're working in an area which was not supported when VS2005 was shipped. You should at least be using VS2008 for its .NET 3.5 support. If you weren't changing your application, then I wouldn't suggest  upgrading at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else runs across the same issue, I was able to solve this issue by using the WSDL.exe program that is normally found in 2. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\`.

This program creates a proxy class for a web service that allows you to call the API's methods localy in your code.

In command line WSDL.exe is called like this: 3.

```
wsdl http://host/web_service/web_service.asmx?WSDL
```